# Is it verified that iPad cannot create ad hoc wifi networks?

Tags: ipad, networking, wifi, adhoc

Has anyone been able to verify that the iPad cannot create an ad hoc network?

It has different radio hardware (the fact that it does 802.11n demonstrates this) than the iPhones, which I thought was the reason that the iPhones could not create WiFi networks.

I know this was sort of answered elsewhere, but I wanted it to get proper attention with its own question and by more tag coverage.

Jeff, your god of biscuits. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to update this question:  as of iOS 7, the Multipeer Connectivity Framework provides a very high level means of establishing ad-hoc networks via WiFi and/or Bluetooth.  It even bridges from WiFi from/to Bluetooth if some ad-hoc network clients have WiFi off and some have Bluetooth off.

Answer (score 1):

Just looked, and I can't see an option to create an ad hoc network anywhere on my iPad. If it's possible in the hardware, it's certainly not allowed by the software. IMO, I doubt that an app with that sort of functionality would make it through the app store process.

Comment: I know it's not part of the UI, but that doesn't meant it wouldn't be possible programmatically, using valid APIs (even if you had to resort to POSIX-level APIs).

Comment: IIRC, the app store won't allow apis of that nature to be used; so at absolute best a jailbreak would be required.